# React Native, Multiple Autocomplete Dropdown. How do i get all values to one string?

Tags: react-native, autocomplete

https://github.com/maxkordiyak/react-native-dropdown-autocomplete
I found this package when searching for an autocomplete textinput for react-native.
It is very good, but I have one problem how do I get all the lines to one string variable.
How do I get the value of the inputs?

My Code is here:

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, Text} from "react-native";
import {Ionicons} from "@expo/vector-icons";
import {Autocomplete, withKeyboardAwareScrollView} from "react-native-dropdown-autocomplete";
const data = ["apple", "apple2"];

class CodeEditor extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            lineCount: 1,
            code: '',

        }
    }
  handleSelectItem(item, index) {
    const {onDropdownClose} = this.props;
    onDropdownClose();
    console.log(item);
  }

  incrementLines(){
      this.setState({
          lineCount: this.state.lineCount + 1
      })
  }

  render() {
    const autocompletes = [...Array(this.state.lineCount).keys()];

    const apiUrl = "https://5b927fd14c818e001456e967.mockapi.io/branches";

    const {scrollToInput, onDropdownClose, onDropdownShow} = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.autocompletesContainer}>
        <SafeAreaView>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addLine} onPress={() => this.incrementLines()}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center'}}>+</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          {autocompletes.map((_, idx) => (
            <Autocomplete
              key={idx.toString()}
              style={styles.input}
              scrollToInput={ev => scrollToInput(ev)}
              handleSelectItem={(item, id) => this.handleSelectItem(item, id)}
              onDropdownClose={() => onDropdownClose()}
              onDropdownShow={() => onDropdownShow()}
              renderIcon={() => (
                <Ionicons name="ios-add-circle-outline" size={20} color="#c7c6c1" style={styles.plus} />
              )}
              // fetchDataUrl={apiUrl}
              data={data}
              minimumCharactersCount={0}
              highlightText
              multiline= {true}
              valueExtractor={item => item}
              rightContent
              inputStyle = {styles.inputText}
              rightTextExtractor={item => item}
            />
          ))}
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  autocompletesContainer: {
    paddingTop: 0,
    zIndex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  },
  input: {width: Dimensions.get('window').width, textAlign: 'center'},
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
  },
  plus: {
    position: "absolute",
    left: 15,
    top: 10,
  },
  addLine:{
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },
  inputText:{
      width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 1
  }
});

export default withKeyboardAwareScrollView(CodeEditor);
```

The user can add a line when pressing on the Touchable-Highlight.
And then he can submit a post but how do i get all of the values from the lines to a single string?
I tried using the HandleSelectedItem but that didnt work out.
Also im trying to learn react native right now so im not that good in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have different functions that handles the selection and safe each value in another variable like this:

```js
  handleSelectItem1(item, index) {
    const {onDropdownClose} = this.props;
    onDropdownClose();
    this.item1 = item;
  }
  handleSelectItem2(item, index) {
    const {onDropdownClose} = this.props;
    onDropdownClose();
    this.item2 = item;
  }
render() {
return (
...
            <Autocomplete
              key={shortid.generate()}
              style={styles.input}
              scrollToInput={ev => scrollToInput(ev)}
              handleSelectItem={(item, id) => this.handleSelectItem1(item, id)}
              onDropdownClose={() => onDropdownClose()}
              onDropdownShow={() => onDropdownShow()}
              renderIcon={() => (
                <Ionicons name="ios-add-circle-outline" size={20} color="#c7c6c1" style={styles.plus} />
              )}
              fetchDataUrl={apiUrl}
              minimumCharactersCount={2}
              highlightText
              valueExtractor={item => item.name}
              rightContent
              rightTextExtractor={item => item.properties}
            />
          ))}
            <Autocomplete
              key={shortid.generate()}
              style={styles.input}
              scrollToInput={ev => scrollToInput(ev)}
              handleSelectItem={(item, id) => this.handleSelectItem2(item, id)}
              onDropdownClose={() => onDropdownClose()}
              onDropdownShow={() => onDropdownShow()}
              renderIcon={() => (
                <Ionicons name="ios-add-circle-outline" size={20} color="#c7c6c1" style={styles.plus} />
              )}
              fetchDataUrl={apiUrl}
              minimumCharactersCount={2}
              highlightText
              valueExtractor={item => item.name}
              rightContent
              rightTextExtractor={item => item.properties}
            />
          ))}
...
)
```

To save the text without select, listen to onChangeText it will look something like that

```js
  onChangeText(item) {
    this.item1 = item;
  }
```

Comment: i know but the problem is that if the user types a word without using the autocomplete it doesnt get added.

Comment: For this, you need to listen to this function onChangeText, and save the data in the var, I will update the answer as well, so you can mark and upvote